# How to check that timezone exists with boost locale

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, locale

I need to parse time from string (`%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%s`) according to some timezone.

My first idea was to try `boost::date_time`, however it looks like its database is outdated and timezone detection algorithm is wrong in general. So I decided to try `boost::locale`. It has [ICU backend](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone), so timezone support should be good. I use the following code:

```
namespace as = boost::locale::as;

void foo(std::string time, std::string timezone) {
    auto glob = boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global();
    glob.select("icu"); // select icu backend
    boost::locale::generator gen{glob};

    auto loc = gen.generate(""); // generate locale with boost facets
    auto cal = boost::locale::calendar{loc, timezone};

    boost::locale::date_time dt{cal};

    std::stringstream ss{time};
    ss.imbue(loc);
    std::cout.imbue(loc);

    ss >> as::ftime("%Y-%m-%d %T") >> as::time_zone(timezone) >> dt;
    std::cout << as::time_zone("UTC") << dt << std::endl;
    std::cout << as::time_zone(timezone) << dt << std::endl;
}
```

This works well, however if I pass some invalid timezone name ("foo"), the library accepts it, no exception is thrown, the time is parsed as if it is UTC time. That's not good for me, I want to detect this case somehow, so that I can notify user that the result will not be what he/she expects.

My first idea was to check `cal.get_time_zone()`, but it always returns the string that was passed to constructor ("foo" in my case), no matter if it's valid or not.

Next, I tried to extract `calendar_facet` from the generated locale, like so:

```
const auto &icu_cal = std::use_facet<boost::locale::calendar_facet>(loc);
```

so that I can access an internal `abstract_calendar` class. Unfortunately, this line doesn't compile. The reason is that `boost/locale/generator.hpp` has a static constant with the same name (`calendar_facet`) in the same `boost::locale` namespace. The compiler reports that it can not instantiate `std::use_facet`. Maybe I can move it to a separate compilation unit and avoid including `generator.hpp` header there, but it looks like a hack for me. Is it a bug or I'm missing something here?

Is there a straightforward way how to validate timezone name with `boost::locale`? Do you recommend it in general? Thanks for your help.

Edit: here is a minimal example of code that doesn't compile for me

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
int main() {
  auto my = boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global();
  my.select("icu");
  boost::locale::generator gen{my};
  std::use_facet<boost::locale::calendar_facet>(gen.generate(""));
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it like so (on ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4):

```
g++ -std=c++14 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ test.cpp -lboost_locale -lboost_date_time
```

Edit 2: With Sehe's help I managed to get calendar facet from locale and now can I check timezone like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  auto my = boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global();
  my.select("icu");
  boost::locale::generator gen{my};
  auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<boost::locale::abstract_calendar>(std::use_facet<class boost::locale::calendar_facet>(gen.generate("")).create_calendar());
  ptr->set_timezone(argv[1]);
  // if ICU backend does not recognize timezone, it sets it to Etc/Unknown
  if (ptr->get_timezone() != argv[1]) {
      std::cout << "bad timezone " << ptr->get_timezone() << std::endl;
  } else {
      std::cout << "good timezone " << ptr->get_timezone() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Update:** while I managed to make boost locale do what I want on linux, I later faced some weird errors when I ported my code to OS X (it looks like mac doesn't have ICU backend by default...). So, I decided to switch to [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) instead. This library is of a high quality, works well on both linux and mac, author is helpful and responsive, so highly recommended.

Comment: No samples? No self-contained code?

Comment: I don't know about Boost Locale, but ICU itself has a similar quirk: `createTimeZone()` never returns null, but it does return the same value as `getUnknown()` so you need to compare against that every time to see if you got a "bad" timezone.  See `createTimeZone()` here: http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1TimeZone.html#a35da0507b62754ffe5d8d59c19775cdb

Comment: @sehe I've added an example of code that doesn't compile for me, is it ok?

Comment: Is your question about a particular trick not compiling, or do you want reliable TZ parsing?

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes, I've read about it, but at least in icu it is possible to compare against `getUnknown()`. So I thought maybe something similar is possible with boost..

Comment: @sehe I want reliable TZ parsing of course! well, I thought parsing this way is reliable... Am I wrong? :)

Comment: Well. I'm looking at it, but your code doesn't even bother to check the result of `ss >> ...` - so I wouldn't expect it to be reliable. Anyways, I'm wasting all my time finding whether the `as::ftime` manipulator has any effect on `istream` (doesn't look like it with the name of the `strftime` formatting flag).

Comment: @sehe Okay, that's a good point, I should be more careful with streams here. In fact I posted a minimal example, will fix it in real code, thanks. In fact first code sample works, the only problem is that I have no idea how to check timezone name.

Comment: To my surprise I can only confirm that it's easy to make the library do bogus things (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4808b95debb0c7af). I can only constructively look at something completely different that I made: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091087/85371

Comment: @sehe If I got it right, your code uses strptime's %Z format character, I thought about using it instead of boost and icu, however, according to `man strptime` on mac os X, it only accepts local timezone or "GMT". I have to support linux and os X in my code, so I can't relay on strptime for timezones, I'm afraid.

Comment: Too bad. I admit I only really tested that function on Linux (FreeBSD a long time ago). Good luck with your quest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [alternative timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) that may be easier to use:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        auto tz = date::locate_zone(argv[1]);
        std::cout << "good timezone " << tz->name() << std::endl;
        date::local_seconds tp;
        std::istringstream in{"2017-09-08 11:30:15"};
        in >> date::parse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tp);
        auto zt = date::make_zoned(tz, tp);
        std::cout << date::format("%Y-%m-%d %T %Z which is ", zt);
        std::cout << date::format("%Y-%m-%d %T %Z\n", zt.get_sys_time());
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "bad timezone " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Sample output 1:

```
good timezone America/New_York
2017-09-08 11:30:15 EDT which is 2017-09-08 15:30:15 UTC
```

Sample output 2:

```
bad timezone America/New_Yor not found in timezone database
```

Comment: In fact I thought about it, read the docs and I liked the api. Thanks for your work on chrono and date libs. The only thing that stops me from using date in my project is that I'm not sure how stable is it now? In my understanding it's a prototype for the future standardization, isn't it? Do you recommend using it in production already?

Comment: The last time there was a major incompatible API change was May 21, 2016.  I changed the name of `day_point` to `sys_days`.  I didn't do that lightly as I had lots of clients at the time.  But it was necessary, and I documented it as well as I could.  A simple search/replace fixed the issue.  Almost all of the other changes have been backwards compatible.  If I do need to change something, I will be noisy about it, with instructions on how to port.  If changes need to be tried out for standardization, I'll float them on the `std` branch before merging to `master`.

Comment: Yes, people are using this in production, and I take that seriously.  It is likely there will be further changes as this gets standardized.  But this implementation and API won't go away any time soon.  I will allow years of migration time from this lib to a std one should it be standardized.  And the very soonest standardization could take place is 2020.

Comment: I tried date library and decided to switch to it from boost locale. Date library is much cleaner and easier to use. So, I'll mark this as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The fix to the non-compiling sample:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4555db7551886207)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
int main() {
  auto my = boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global();
  my.select("icu");
  boost::locale::generator gen{my};
  std::use_facet<class boost::locale::calendar_facet>(gen.generate(""));
}
```

Comment: Please check my second update. I extract an abstract calendar from calendar facet (it is implemented in ICU backend) and get timezone name from it. What do you think, is it ok?

Comment: @PavelDavydov that looks promising. I'd make sure that the type of the timezone you compare to is `std::string`, so as to avoid any questions in review (also, check `argc` :)). And all these things would only pass my review with exhaustive tests. But - at least you found a way forward for the TZ part

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sure, I'll fix the issues and add tests before using this code.