# How to enforce strict parsing in Boost::DateTime

Tags: c++, boost

In the application I'm working on, I receive as an input a datetime in ISO format ( %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ ).

I'd like to check that the received string is indeed in the specified format. I wanted to try the Boost DateTime library, which seemed perfect for this task.

However, I am surprised by the behavior of the DateTime parsing. My code is the following:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::string inputDate = "2017-01-31T02:15:53Z";
  std::string expectedFormat = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ";

  boost::posix_time::time_input_facet *timeFacet = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet(expectedFormat);

  std::stringstream datetimeStream(inputDate);
  datetimeStream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), timeFacet));

  boost::posix_time::ptime outputTime;
  datetimeStream >> outputTime;
  if (datetimeStream.fail())
  {
    std::cout << "Failure" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << outputTime << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When running this program, the output is:

```
2017-Jan-31 02:15:53
```

As expected. However if I change the inputDate to an invalid datetime like **"2017-01-31T02:15:63Z"** (63 seconds should not be accepted), the output will be

```
2017-Jan-31 02:16:03
```

Instead of a "Failure" message. I understand the logic behind, but I'd like to enforce a more strict parsing. Moreover, the parsing will still work when using  **"2017-01-31T02:15:53Z I like Stackoverflow"** as the input, which is even stranger considering it doesn't respect the specified format.

So my question is: How to force Boost DateTime to reject strings that are not strictly respecting the format defined in the time_input_facet ?

Thanks

Comment: would a regex work?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474237/c-boost-date-input-facet-seems-to-parse-dates-unexpectedly-with-incorrect-form/46478956#46478956

Comment: Regex is what I ended up doing. My work environment does not allow me to use libraries freely (needs to be checked by the managment for licensing etc ... So quite difficult) and strptime seemed the way to go BUT it is also not allowed because it is not standard and available on every OS :(

Comment: I'm trying to get my library into the standard:  https://wg21.link/p0355  Maybe your management will approve it after that. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use another [free, open-source, header-only date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html)?

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::string inputDate = "2017-01-31T02:15:63Z";
    std::string expectedFormat = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ";
    std::stringstream datetimeStream{inputDate};
    date::sys_seconds outputTime;
    datetimeStream >> date::parse(expectedFormat, outputTime);
    if (datetimeStream.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Failure" << std::endl;
    }
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << outputTime << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Failure
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: nitpick: I would not be couting outputTime since parsing failed.... I know it is just example, but... I would put it in else {}

Comment: I would too.  But I made a point of doing a literal translation of the OP's code, including using the same variable names, and including the same bugs.

Comment: b29 bullet holes ;)

Comment: LOL!  I had never heard of that reference before.  Great story and analogy! :-)

Comment: Yes you are right about not outputing outputTime in case of error ... It was a sample code I made for explaining my problem :) The library would be the cleanest solution so I'm going to accept it but I cannot use it in my work environment :(