# Parse datetime with timezone using Boost.Date_Time?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I want to parse date time with time-zone using [Boost Date Time IO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) library.

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point ParseDate(const std::wstring& dateText, const wchar_t* const format) {
    ptime time;
    std::wstringstream buffer(dateText);
    buffer.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new wtime_input_facet(format)));
    buffer >> time;
    auto timeInfo = to_tm(time);
    auto result = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&timeInfo));
    return result;
}

TEST_CLASS(DateUtilsTest) {
public:
    TEST_METHOD(ShouldParseUtcDate) {
        auto timePoint = ParseDate(L"2016-12-03T07:09:01-05:00", L"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Q");
        auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timePoint);
        auto timePoint2 = ParseDate(L"2016-12-03T07:09:01", L"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
        auto time2 = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(timePoint2);
        Assert::IsTrue(time != time2);
    }
}
```

Here's an **online example**: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9GEhah5l4uzhgDta

The above test failed because time == time2.

It seems that the time-zone portion doesn't have any impact to the parsing result.

Do you know how to parse a date time string with time-zone using Boost?

The real case is string like "**2017-12-21T10:47:58.299Z**" (ISO 8601 format, generated by JavaScript: `(new Date()).toISOString()`), but I didn't find any doc for this format, any ideas?

Environment:

- Boost-1.65.1
- System is Windows 10
- System time-zone is GMT+8
- Visual Studio 2015U3

Comment: Looks like this indeed just a typo. Then this question can be closed.

Comment: @Ivan not so sure yet. There's more

Comment: Updated with an online example.

Comment: Sure would be easy using [Howard's timezone lib](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) :-)

Comment: [For example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T0Ng1gES8X0Na4uG).

Comment: @HowardHinnant Is there a way to parse time like "2017-12-21T10:47:58.299Z"? Is there any doc for format "%Ez"?

Comment: Yes, you can parse fractional seconds. Just create a type that holds the precision you want to parse into and use that in place of where my example uses `sys_seconds`. For example I could have parsed into a `system_clock::time_point` (which has microseconds precision on my platform), and that would allow for parsing up to microseconds precision with the %S and %T flags. Here is full documentation for all of the parsing flags: ttps://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#from_stream_formatting  You can parse your case with `"%FT%TZ"` into a `time_point` with precision milliseconds or greater.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KE8UCpR3GJaZPrts

Comment: Updated docs link:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#from_stream_formatting

Comment: Look good. What does "%FT" stands for? I failed with "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%TZ" which I thought the same as "%FT%TZ". It's better to document the special %FT, %TZ although it is already complicated.

Comment: `"%FT"` is equivalent to `"%Y-%m-%dT"`.  You can parse with `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`, which is equivalent to `"%FT%TZ"`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant 
https://wandbox.org/permlink/MgdMwlKHnFNxEJb2 I may be wrong, does 'Z' suffix stands for UTC? Why I got same output?

Comment: `Z` just stands for the literal `Z`.  It doesn't mean anything at all.  The type `system_clock::time_point` means UTC (excluding leap seconds).  If you've got a `system_clock::time_point`, it represents UTC.  There are ways to represent local time.  You'll need the "tz.h" portion of this library to handle local time / time zones, which requires a source file and some installation on Windows:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation

Comment: Slight correction.  If the only way you need to represent local time is by parsing UTC offsets as you showed earlier, you can stick with the header-only "date.h".  "tz.h" is needed for named IANA time zones, and your computer's current local time zone.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601, there is a 'UTC' section, says:
"Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. " F.Y.I

Comment: <shrug>  If you put a `"Z"` in the format string, the parse will demand to parse a `Z` in the input, else it won't.  If you successfully parse into a `time_point<system_clock, Duration>`, that quantity will be interpreted as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  You can parse into a `time_point<system_clock, Duration>` with or without using a `Z`, your choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked at it long and hard. It seems you're almost completely out of luck:

[image]

---

So you can try making it work with `%ZP`.

### Doing The Heroics

I did the heroics, only to find out that the support for `wtime_zone` and friends is ... incomplete in the library.

Here it is in all it g(l)ory:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20cf65b4e0fb91a0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/time_zone_base.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>

namespace DT = boost::date_time;
namespace LT = boost::local_time;
namespace PT = boost::posix_time;

template <typename CharT = wchar_t> struct TypeDefs {
    using ptime   = PT::ptime;
    using tz_base = DT::time_zone_base<ptime, CharT>;
    using tz_ptr  = boost::shared_ptr<DT::time_zone_base<PT::ptime, CharT> >;
    using ptz_t   = LT::posix_time_zone_base<CharT>;
    using ldt_t   = LT::local_date_time_base<ptime, tz_base>;
};

namespace boost { namespace local_time { 
  //! input operator for local_date_time
  template <class CharT, class Traits, typename Defs = TypeDefs<CharT>, typename local_date_time = typename Defs::ldt_t>
  inline
  std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
  operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& is, local_date_time& ldt)
  {
    using time_zone_ptr = typename Defs::tz_ptr;
    using posix_time_zone = typename Defs::ptz_t;
    boost::io::ios_flags_saver iflags(is);
    typename std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>::sentry strm_sentry(is, false);
    if (strm_sentry) {
      try {
        typedef typename local_date_time::utc_time_type utc_time_type;
        typedef typename date_time::time_input_facet<utc_time_type, CharT> time_input_facet;

        // intermediate objects
        std::basic_string<CharT> tz_str;
        utc_time_type pt(DT::not_a_date_time); 

        std::istreambuf_iterator<CharT,Traits> sit(is), str_end;
        if(std::has_facet<time_input_facet>(is.getloc())) {
          std::use_facet<time_input_facet>(is.getloc()).get_local_time(sit, str_end, is, pt, tz_str);
        }
        else {
          time_input_facet* f = new time_input_facet();
          std::locale l = std::locale(is.getloc(), f);
          is.imbue(l);
          f->get_local_time(sit, str_end, is, pt, tz_str);
        }
        if(tz_str.empty()) {
          time_zone_ptr null_ptr;
          // a null time_zone_ptr creates a local_date_time that is UTC
          ldt = local_date_time(pt, null_ptr);
        }
        else {
          time_zone_ptr tz_ptr(new posix_time_zone(tz_str));
          // the "date & time" constructor expects the time label to *not* be utc.
          // a posix_tz_string also expects the time label to *not* be utc.
          ldt = local_date_time(pt.date(), pt.time_of_day(), tz_ptr, local_date_time::EXCEPTION_ON_ERROR);
        }
      }
      catch(...) {
        // mask tells us what exceptions are turned on
        std::ios_base::iostate exception_mask = is.exceptions();
        // if the user wants exceptions on failbit, we'll rethrow our 
        // date_time exception & set the failbit
        if(std::ios_base::failbit & exception_mask) {
          try { is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); }
          catch(std::ios_base::failure&) {} // ignore this one
          throw; // rethrow original exception
        }
        else {
          // if the user want's to fail quietly, we simply set the failbit
          is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }

      }
    }
    return is;
  }
} }

template <typename CharT = wchar_t> struct DateUtilsBase : TypeDefs<CharT> {

    using base = TypeDefs<CharT>;
    using typename base::ldt_t;
    using typename base::tz_ptr;
    using typename base::ptime;

    static std::tm to_tm(ldt_t const& lt) {
        std::tm v = PT::to_tm(lt.local_time());
        v.tm_isdst = lt.is_dst()? 1:0;
        return v;
    }

    static tz_ptr s_GMT;

    static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point Parse(const std::basic_string<CharT>& dateText, const CharT* const format) {

        ldt_t value(LT::special_values::not_a_date_time, s_GMT);

        std::basic_istringstream<CharT> buffer(dateText);
        buffer.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new DT::time_input_facet<ptime, CharT>(format)));

        std::basic_string<CharT> dummy;
        if (buffer >> value && (buffer >> dummy).eof()) {
            std::cout << "DEBUG: " << value.utc_time() << " EOF:" << buffer.eof() << "\n";
            auto timeInfo = PT::to_tm(value.utc_time());
            return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&timeInfo));
        } else {
            return std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::min();
        }
    }
};

template <> typename DateUtilsBase<wchar_t>::tz_ptr DateUtilsBase<wchar_t>::s_GMT { new ptz_t(L"GMT") } ;
template <> typename DateUtilsBase<char>::tz_ptr    DateUtilsBase<char>::s_GMT    { new ptz_t("GMT")  } ;

#if 1
    using DateUtils = DateUtilsBase<wchar_t>;
    #define T(lit) L##lit
#else
    using DateUtils = DateUtilsBase<char>;
    #define T(lit) lit
#endif

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using C = std::chrono::system_clock;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::unitbuf;

    C::time_point with_zone, without_zone;

    // all three equivalent:
    with_zone = DateUtils::Parse(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01 PST-05:00"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%ZP"));
    with_zone = DateUtils::Parse(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01 -05:00"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%ZP"));
    with_zone = DateUtils::Parse(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01-05:00"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%ZP"));

    without_zone = DateUtils::Parse(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"));
    std::cout << "time_point equal? " << (with_zone == without_zone) << "\n";

    {
        std::time_t t_with_zone    = C::to_time_t(with_zone);
        std::time_t t_without_zone = C::to_time_t(without_zone);

        std::cout << "time_t equal? " << (t_with_zone == t_without_zone) << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << (without_zone - with_zone) / 1h << " hours difference\n";
}
```

Yep. That's a bit of a monstrosity. It prints:

```
DEBUG: 2016-Dec-03 12:09:01 EOF:true
DEBUG: 2016-Dec-03 12:09:01 EOF:true
DEBUG: 2016-Dec-03 12:09:01 EOF:true
DEBUG: 2016-Dec-03 07:09:01 EOF:true
time_point equal? false
time_t equal? false
-5 hours difference
```

### Back To Sanity

In fact, the library authors (wisely) decided that even though streams would be wide or narrow, the `local_date_time` (or really, just the strings in their time-zone representations) need not be. This is why the library supplied `operator>>` only supports `local_date_time` and [employs the internal helper function `convert_string_type` to coerce to narrow-char timezone info](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/boost/date_time/local_time/local_time_io.hpp):

```
time_zone_ptr tz_ptr(new posix_time_zone(date_time::convert_string_type<CharT,char>(tz_str)));
```

With that in mind let's remove a lot "generic-y" cruft. What remains is the addition of error-handling:

```
if (buffer >> value && (buffer >> dummy).eof()) {
    //std::cout << "DEBUG: " << value.utc_time() << " EOF:" << buffer.eof() << "\n";
    auto timeInfo = boost::posix_time::to_tm(value.utc_time());
    return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&timeInfo));
} else {
    return std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::min();
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29148d6740a75a2e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time_io.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>

struct DateUtils {
    using ptime           = boost::posix_time::ptime;
    using time_zone_ptr   = boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr;
    using local_date_time = boost::local_time::local_date_time;

    template <typename CharT>
    static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point Parse(const std::basic_string<CharT>& dateText, const CharT* const format) {
        static time_zone_ptr s_GMT(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("GMT"));

        local_date_time value(boost::local_time::special_values::not_a_date_time, s_GMT);

        std::basic_istringstream<CharT> buffer(dateText);
        buffer.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::date_time::time_input_facet<ptime, CharT>(format)));

        std::basic_string<CharT> dummy;
        if (buffer >> value && (buffer >> dummy).eof()) {
            //std::cout << "DEBUG: " << value.utc_time() << " EOF:" << buffer.eof() << "\n";
            auto timeInfo = boost::posix_time::to_tm(value.utc_time());
            return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&timeInfo));
        } else {
            return std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::min();
        }
    }
};

#if 1
    using CharT = wchar_t;
    #define T(lit) L##lit
#else
    using CharT = char;
    #define T(lit) lit
#endif

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using C = std::chrono::system_clock;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::unitbuf;

    C::time_point with_zone, without_zone;

    // all three equivalent:
    with_zone = DateUtils::Parse<CharT>(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01 PST-05:00"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%ZP"));
    with_zone = DateUtils::Parse<CharT>(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01 -05:00"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%ZP"));
    with_zone = DateUtils::Parse<CharT>(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01-05:00"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%ZP"));

    without_zone = DateUtils::Parse<CharT>(T("2016-12-03T07:09:01"), T("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"));
    std::cout << "time_point equal? " << (with_zone == without_zone) << "\n";

    {
        std::time_t t_with_zone    = C::to_time_t(with_zone);
        std::time_t t_without_zone = C::to_time_t(without_zone);

        std::cout << "time_t equal? " << (t_with_zone == t_without_zone) << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << (without_zone - with_zone) / 1h << " hours difference\n";
}
```

Whew. From 151 LoC down to 64 LoC. Better

Prints:

```
time_point equal? false
time_t equal? false
-5 hours difference
```

### Summary:

- ***read (all) the notes in the docs***
- use `%ZP` as the only supported input format
- use `local_date_time` because that format string is ignored with `ptime` (it says so in the notes)
- use error handling to make sure no "unparsed" things are left behind in the input

---

Comment: That's a typo, but still doesn't work after fix. Please have a look the updated version.

Comment: I figured things out the hard way. Boost DateTime is never as user-friendly as one would hope. Anyways... it works now :) Just for completeness I'm going to point out I usually roll with `strptime` and my [`adaptive_parser` helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083239/using-boost-parse-datetime-string-with-single-digit-hour-format/44091087#44091087)